# SharePoint 2010 Drop off library with approval before moving document?

Tags: 2010, drop-off-library

I have a drop off library with some rules and when they are fulfilled the documents are moved to other libraries depending on what metadata was specified.

I have a requirement where one group of people should be able to upload documents to the drop off library and another group that should approve them before they are moved, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

You can use [OOB Content Approval](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a-library-HA010172010.aspx) for Drop-Off Library.. since Drop-Off Library is a standard document library you can use Workflows with it!

Or you can create your own custom Workflow using SP Designer or Visual Studio and bind it to work with Drop-Off Library..

More Reading:
[SharePoint 2010 Content Organizer Part 3 - The Drop Off Library](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/30/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-3-the-rules-engine.aspx)

I hope this helps

Comment: yeah I read "Content Approval - items can be forced through a content approval process prior to it being routed" but the thing is that the approval process is ignored, if the metadata is filled out the document is moved. I have set library settings to "require content approval - yes
Create Major versions
Require documents to be checked out - yes" and the approval workflow starts on item created/item changed but as I said the document is moved before any workflow task is created.

Comment: what are the main features of Drop off library?

Comment: @Venu please ask a new question and experts will answer accordingly..

Comment: You can create rule like and condition between approval workflow column and metadata column in list so what happen when workflow completed then approval workflow column have value othrws till document not moved if there is no value in approval column.